# How to be comfortable with JSLint validator?

Tags: javascript, validation, jslint

Using JSLint since some month, I wonder how to be comfortable with it?

IMO the official website is too basic. No line number in the code editor, no links between error and code, poor presentation...

And using in CLI, is also not the more comfortable way.

So the question is: "How do you use JSLint?". What are your practices and recommendation to perform using JSLint? Is there any alternative online checker that are more powerful? Or maybe advanced online editor that include JSLint validator?

Comment: what scripting language are you using??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried JSHint?

[JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/)

It's a fork of JSLinl with some upgrades, for example like line number.

Anyway there're some plugin that you could add to your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Visual Studio I highly recommend the [JSLint.VS2010 Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/961e6734-cd3a-4afb-a121-4541742b912e). It integrates directly into the IDE. A few features I really like:

- Choice of JSLint or JSHint (I prefer JSHint)
- Granular control of check options to enable/disable exactly what gets validated
- Automatically check files on project build
- Ability to exclude files from check (useful for external libraries such as JQuery)
- Right-click in IDE window to validate current file instantly
- Ability to comment individual lines or code blocks to prevent validation. Useful when you want to break the rules deliberately occasionally
- Click on warning message takes me directly to the offending line of code

Answer (score 2):

Don't be afraid to fork. JSLint is based on Crockford's personal ideas of code quality, and you might think different.

I use JSLint ("improved" version) as a pre-commit hook in git. This requires some Node or rhino installation, and saves me the trouble of running it manually.

Remember:

> JSLint will hurt your feelings

Answer (score 0):

You can get JSLint plugins for your preferred IDE. I use a JSLint validator along with Resharper 6 in Visual Studio, which gives me all of the things that you mention (I click on a warning, it takes me to the line of code).

On [the JS Lint website](http://www.jslint.com/) you should get the line number and character along with a code snippet for any error in the warning message:

> Problem at line 10 character 13: A constructor name 'myObject' should
>   start with an uppercase letter.
>
> var x = new myObject();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make JSLint part of your build process, do check out [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/).  It works great for Java projects, but can also be applied to non-Java projects.